# My jQuery code doesn't answer to button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to use jQuery in order to get some text written on the same page I have opened. I inserted a button, but it is not working on my Django server. After doing some research I noticed that the code works on some servers and doesn't work on others.

For example, I wrote the snippet below and it will be posible to notice that buttons work on it, but when I bring it to my server or to [repl.it](https://repl.it/@educlj/CrazyAttractiveMedian), the first button never works.

I intend to use exactly the first button example to produce my codes. Can anyone help me to clarify the reasons the above mentioned button doesn't work sometimes?

```js
$("#sentiment_training").click(function(){
    /* This is a work in progress yet */
    alert("Using jQuery in a File");
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("Alert with inline script");
};

$("#sentiment_training3").click(function(){
    /* This is a work in progress yet */
    alert("Using jQuery Inline");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="sentiment_training" name="sentiment_training" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">jQuery in a file</button>


<button id="sentiment_training2" name="sentiment_training2" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" onclick="myFunction()">JavaScript Inline!</button>

<button id="sentiment_training3" name="sentiment_training3" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">jQuery Inline</button>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look into `$(document).ready()` and `.on()`

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that the document is not yet loaded at the script's runtime. Moving your scripts to the end of `body` is a solution. You can also create an event, which will be triggered on document load and run your script afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code inside a [`$(document).ready(function() {})`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) block.
This ensures that the code will only run after document is "ready."

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sentiment_training3").click(function(){
    /* This is a work in progress yet */
    alert("Using jQuery Inline");
  });
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, guys! You helped me a lot! <3 (Y)